# Insert into 3 different tables

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a form that is connected with the db. I wrote the insert statement but it says that I have an error and I can't find it. My purpose is to fill the form and the values are going to be saved in 3 different tables in the db. This is a part of my code.
This is the insert statement:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO Gjinekologjia VALUES(
    '" .$_POST['Nr_kartele'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Emri'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Mbiemri'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Mosha'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Pariteti'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['E_siguruar'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Adresa'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Dt_e_shtrimit'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Dite_qendrimi'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Diagnoza'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Nomenkletura'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Intervent'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Intervent_urgjent'] . "',



    '" .$_POST['Hemotransfuzion'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Material_per_biopsi'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Histerectomi'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Plastike'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Adnexectomi'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Abrazio'] . "',



    '" .$_POST['HSG'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['LEEP'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['PAP'] . "',
    '" .$_POST['Colposcopi'] . "')

    UNION 
    INSERT INTO abortet values ('" .$_POST['Nderpreje_e_vullnetshme'] . "',
                                '" .$_POST['Abort_spontan'] . "',
                                '" .$_POST['Missed_abortion'] . "')
    UNION 
    INSERT INTO komplikacion_i_interventit values ( '" .$_POST['Infeksion'] . "',
                                                    '" .$_POST['Hemoragji'] . "',
                                                    '" .$_POST['Ileus'] . "')

    RIGHT JOIN abortet
    ON Gjinekologjia.ID_Abortet=abortet.ID_Abortet,
    LEFT JOIN komplikacion_i_interventit
    ON Gjinekologjia.ID_Komplikacion_i_interventit=komplikacion_i_interventit.ID_Komplikacion_i_interventit;";
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="Gjinekologjia.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Nr i karteles:</label>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nr_kartele" name="Nr_kartele" placeholder="Nr i karteles i pacientit">
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Emri:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Emri" name="Emri" placeholder="Shkruani emrin e pacientit">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Mbiemri:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Mbiemri" name="Mbiemri" placeholder="Shkruani mbiemrin e pacientit">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Mosha:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Mosha" name="Mosha" placeholder="Shkruani moshen e pacientit">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Pariteti:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Pariteti" value="1">Primipare</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Pariteti" value="0">Pluripare</label>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">E siguruar:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="E_siguruar" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="E_siguruar" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Adresa:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Adresa" value="1">Qytet</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Adresa" value="0">Fshat</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Data e shtrimit:</label>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dt_e_shtrimit" name="Dt_e_shtrimit" placeholder="Shkruani daten e shtrimit te pacientit">
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Dite qendrimi:</label>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dite_qendrimi" name="Dite_qendrimi" placeholder="Shkruani ditet e qendrimit te pacientit">
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Diagnoza:</label>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Diagnoza" name="Diagnoza" placeholder="Shkruani diagnozen e pacientit">
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Nomenkletura:</label>

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nomenkletura" name="Nomenkletura" placeholder="Shkruani Nomenkleturen e pacientit">
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Intervent:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Intervent" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Intervent" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Intervent urgjent:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Intervent_urgjent" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Intervent_urgjent" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

  <h3>Komplikacion i interventit</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Infeksion:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Infeksion" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Infeksion" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Hemoragji:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Hemoragji" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Hemoragji" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Ileus:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Ileus" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Ileus" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Hemotransfuzion:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Hemotransfuzion" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Hemotransfuzion" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Material per biopsi:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Material_per_biopsi" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Material_per_biopsi" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Histerectomi:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Histerectomi" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Histerectomi" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Plastike:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Plastike" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Plastike" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Adnexectomi:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Adnexectomi" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Adnexectomi" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Abrazio:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Abrazio" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Abrazio" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3>Abortet</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Nderpreje e vullnetshme:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Nderpreje_e_vullnetshme" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Nderpreje_e_vullnetshme" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Abort spontan:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Abort_spontan" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Abort_spontan" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Missed abortion:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Missed_abortion" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Missed_abortion" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">HSG:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="HSG" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="HSG" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">LEEP:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="LEEP" value= "1">Po</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="LEEP" value= "0">Jo</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">PAP Test:</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="PAP" value="Normale">Normale</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="PAP" value="Jo_normale">Jo normale</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="PAP" value="Jo">Jo</label>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Colposcopi</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Colposcopi" value="Pozitive">Pozitive</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Colposcopi" value="Negative">Negative</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="Colposcopi" value="Jo">Jo</label>
        </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="ruaj" >Ruaj</button>


  </form>
```

Please help me...

Comment: You can't do INSERT...UNION...INSERT, you have to run each insert separately.

Comment: I ran each insert separately and it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Important things first: What you create is a SQL injection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Please use prepared statements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

You dont specify the used sql dialect. Without this information it is not possible to answer this question 100% correctly. But I know no dialect where a union in a insert statement is possible.